# Application causing exception during scheduled time

Tags: .net, oracle, scheduled-tasks, console-application, arcobjects

I am getting below mentioned exception only when I am scheduling my application to run on particular time.

"The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))"

This does not happen when i run the application manually.

This is a Arcgis & .Net based console application.

I am using same user to run manually as well as in Task Scheduler (selected option Run whether user is logged on or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution to this problem it was due to lack of privilege.

So I just enabled Run with highest privilege option and that solved the problem.